# AppleScript JavaScript getElements

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, javascript

I have my script partially working. I'm using AppleScript to script interactions with Chrome.

```
set textToSave to "Text"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's tab 1 javascript "document.getElementsByName('0.9.7.1.5.0.4.1.3')[0].click();"
    delay 0.1
```

1. If I enter a multiple line textToSave for example

   ```
   " here
   blabla 

   bla"
   ```

   then I have no text and --> missing value
2. I need to set a popup field before this script, here is the HTML for it

   ```
   <select id="PaymentEnSelection" name="0.9.7.1.5.9.4.1.9"> <option selected="selected" value="0">Enabled</option> <option value="1">Disabled</option></select>
   ```

   and a another one :

   ```
   <select name="0.9.7.1.9.0.4.1.9.0.2.1.3.7.3.9.3.1"><option value="NoSelectionString">Please select a reason</option>
   <option value="0">R1</option>
   <option value="1">&amp; Review </option>
   <option value="2">Chart</option>
   <option value="3">R3</option>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Multiline text can be achieved using either of the following methods:

- Separate the text by new lines, with the first quote and last quote encapsulating the contents.

  [image]
- Use `\n` as new line.

  ```
  set myvar to "hello\nanother\n\nfinal"
  ```

You can set the value of a select element using the following JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("PaymentEnSelection").value = 1
```

The value given is one of the value attributes on the option elements that you wish to select.

Comment: the first method is the one I usually use, but not working on this case, tried the \n instead, but same issue, for some reason It's only working when I enter one line (or multiple line manual) for the document.getElementById, can I do that my name instead ? I tried your code anyway but have an error , also tried with execute front window's tab 1 javascript "document.getElementByName('0.3.8.1.5.0.4.1.5.0.6.1.3.7.3.1.3.1').value=1" but missing value

Comment: @Kevin Yes, you can use any method which returns an element, so any of the ‘getElement…’ methods will work. There is no such method ‘getElementByName’, you need to ‘getElementsByName’ and index the array. Use the JS console in Chrome to debug your JS before you run the JS in AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

I find it (for the second question)

```
execute front window's tab 1 javascript ¬
        "document.getElementsByName('namehere')[0].selectedIndex=1"
```

the value for selected index is whatever you want to select on the dropdown menu.